# Jenkins Multijob Plugin phase jobs not being displayed

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am currently using Jenkins and the Multijob plugin to split a job into multiple smaller parts; however, I cannot see the phase jobs.

[image]

Here is inside of my job, you can see I have a phase with two jobs that should run sequentially; however, I cannot find these job in order to edit and change them.

[image]

What am I missing here? I cannot seem to view the jobs and edit them

Answer (score 0):

You have to create job with some name and then, in multijob project, you should refer to existing job that you created before.

Please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438313/creating-jobs-for-multijob-plugin-in-jenkins)