# Creating Jobs for Multijob Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I had a requirement for executing jobs in parallel and came across this plugin called MultiJob plugin for Jenkins.

After going through documentation, i created phases and gave job names. But where do i create job basically.I mean the script ,build step and post build step for job "TaskToExecute1" and "TasktoExecute2".

Thanks,
VVP
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the jobs that are referenced from the "Job Name".

So in your example, create a separate job/project (e.g. "New Item" -> "Freestyle Project") and call it TaskToExecute1. Then you can add a build step to that new TaskToExecute job/project.

Comment: Thanks . I got it working now.
But i think it would have been more useful if we had a way to define jobs inside one multijob project, so that we can always know these jobs are not individual ones but part of multijob project.